# Laravel routes same url but different name

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to make a function to create a database row but my routes are not working.
I currenlty have this in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/admin/pagina', [PaginaOverzichtController::class, 'index'])
->name('Admin_Pagina_Overzicht')
->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/admin/pagina', [PaginaOverzichtController::class, 'CreatePage'])
->name('Admin_Pagina_CreatePage')
->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/admin/pagina', [PaginaOverzichtController::class, 'DeletePage'])
->name('Admin_Pagina_DeletePage')
->middleware('auth');
```

But when I go to /admin/pagina, I get a `Route [Admin_Pagina_CreatePage] not defined` error.

Am I allowed to have the same URL but different name pointing to a different function in the same controller? If not, is there a best-practice way to do this?

^
I have a form on my page that should create a page with the method post and action `{{ route('Admin_Pagina_CreatePage') }}`

Answer (score 3):

> Am I allowed to have the same url but differend name pointing to a differend function in the same controller?

No. When determining uniqueness in Laravel routes, the HTTP Method & URI act as a combined primary key. Everything else is just metadata attached to that unique entry.

In your example, the second `Route::post('/admin/pagina')` is *overwriting* the first one, because you've defined the same "ID" pair of `POST /admin/pagina`.

I'm not sure how you expect to have the same HTTP method and URI go to two separate controller actions. If you expect to route them differently based on what's included in the request body, that conflicts with how Laravel's routing works (routes are found and dispatched without usage of the request body).

Normally for a delete, you would utilize that HTTP method in the routing:

```
Route::delete('/admin/pagina' [/* ... */]);
```

This can be paired with [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing) to trick a normal form request (which doesn't support `DELETE`) to find that appropriate route anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Not related to your problem it's just a suggestion*, you can use [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups) and assign a middleware to that group to avoid repetition of assigning one middleware to each route.

E.g.

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/admin/pagina', [PaginaOverzichtController::class, 'index'])->name('Admin_Pagina_Overzicht');

    Route::post('/admin/pagina', [PaginaOverzichtController::class, 'CreatePage'])->name('Admin_Pagina_CreatePage');

    Route::post('/admin/pagina', [PaginaOverzichtController::class, 'DeletePage'])->name('Admin_Pagina_DeletePage');
});
```